# Is there any solution manual for SDE by Bernt Øksendal?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to learn Stochastic differential equations an introduction with applications by Øksendal. Really difficult I feel. Is there solution on the internet? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: The book (at least its newer editions) contains solutions to exercises marked with an asterisk.